# What is the right way to apply target_link_libraries with static library in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am building a library that is linked to a static library. I am trying to figure out a way to propagate just the include and not the library of the static library when I am exporting the targets for the library I am building. Below is an example CMakeLists of the static library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(mystaticlib)

set(PROJECT_SRCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mystatic.cpp)
set(PROJECT_INCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mystatic.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${PROJECT_INCS})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include>)

export(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
      APPEND FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake)
```

very standard and nothing special, now here is my CMakeLists of the library that is linking to this static library

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(testlib)

set(PROJECT_SRCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mytest.cpp)
set(PROJECT_INCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/mytest.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${PROJECT_INCS})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include>)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE mystaticlib)

# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC mystaticlib)

export(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
      APPEND FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}Targets.cmake)
```

The problem of `target_link_libraries` with `PRIVATE` is the include directories from the static library does not get exported. Hence external users links to `testlib` it won't be able to locate where the headers of the static library are.

The problem of `target_link_libraries` with `PUBLIC` is exposing the static library to the external users which is not desired. I only want the external user to be able to link to `testlib`.

What is the right way to solve this?

Comment: what about using INTERFACE instead of PUBLIC or PRIVATE?

Comment: @fedepad If I change it to `INTERFACE` when I compile `testlib` it's not able to locate the headers from `mystaticlib`

Comment: what if in your mystaticlib ` CMakeLists.txt ` you have:
 `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include>) `, although I'm not that confident it's enough as usually you would add INTERFACE to add_library() call, but that is used for header only libraries usually...

Comment: @fedepad If I do that I am not able compile `mystaticlib`, it won't be able to find it's own headers.